# Multiple counters not counting ( foreach / ifs)

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop, counter

This is my first StackOverFlow post.

I have an array of numbers, which I shuffle:

```
$nums = array("1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","4","4","4");
shuffle($nums);
```

1. I am trying to identify a sequence/pattern of any three 3 identical numbers in a row in the shuffled array and
2. output the combined total of all sets of matching numbers.

The problem that I am running into seems to stem from attempting to compare the current number in the loop with the previous number (to see if they match).

When I echo the "previous" number it always outputs as "0".  Thus I am unable to compare the current number and old number, which means I am not able to sum identify and sum a pattern of identical numbers.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$t3count = 0;
$oldnum = 0;
$tots = 0;
$nums = array("1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","4","4","4");
shuffle($nums);
foreach ($nums as $num) {
  echo "$num: [$oldnum] ";
    if ($num = $oldnum) {
      $t3count++;
        if ($t3count = 3) {
          $tots = $num * $num;
          $t3count = 0;
          $oldnum = $num;
        } else {
          # do nonum
        }
      } 
      else {
       $oldnum = $num; 
      }
      # echo "<li>$num</li>";    
   }

 echo "Your total is: $tots";
 unset($num);
```

?>

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do comparison `==` not assignment `=` here:

```
if ($num = $oldnum)
```

and here:

```
if ($t3count = 3)
```

Comment: uggggh! I can't BELIEVE I missed that!  sigh.  Thank you!

Comment: I've finished debugging some of the other errors and wanted to share my progress thus far.  Here is the script thus far.  My next step will be to refactor and put some lipstick on it (html/css).  Thanks once again to everyone who commented:

Answer (score 0):

also this is probably going to bite you if i got the logic right

```
 $t3count++;
 if ($t3count == 3) {
```

how do you know which one counted to 3, id build nested arrays of like values first then process that.

Answer (score 0):

you missed == to compare if ($num = $oldnum)  and if ($t3count = 3)

replace with

if ($num == $oldnum)

if ($t3count == 3)